# open a file which name is contained in a variable

Tags: python, file

I have a hundred of files in a folder which have the form `i.ext` where I is an integer (`0 <= i`). I wrote a script which take 2 files in entries but I wanted to use the script with all the files of my folder.

Could I write a script in Python with a loop such a way that the name file is in a variable like this:

```
from difference import *
# I have a module called "difference"
for i in range (0,100):
 for j in range (0,100):
   leven(i+".ext",j+".ext")          #script in module which take two files in entries
```

Obviously my code is wrong, but I don't know how can I do :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add a number and a string in Python.

```
'%d.ext' % (i,)
```

Answer (score 1):

> but i wanted to use the script with all the files of my folder.Could i write a script in Python with a loop such a way that the name file is in a variable like this:

This is most certainly possible, but if you want to use all the files from a directory following a certain pattern, I suggest you *glob* them.

```
import glob
import difference

ifile_list = glob('*.iext')
jfile_list = glob('*.jext')

for i,j in [[(ifile, jfile) for jfile in jfile_list] for ifile in ifile_list]:
    difference.leven(i,j)
```

However I strongly suggest that instead of hardcodig those file patterns I'd supply them through command line parameters.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion; however, i think it waste a lot of memory bacause i should store the files a second time

Comment: @KKc: You can just use only ifile_list instead. But even storing it a second time wasn't a problem. 100 file names, times 1kB per filename max, makes 100kB for the file names. If this were the 1980-ies I'd say, get that memory footprint down. Today however… pffft.

Answer (score 0):

use `str(i)` and `str(j)` to convert `i` and `j` from **integer** to **str**.